# Too many (redundant?) foreign keys in database schema

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm designing a relational database - with MySQL underneath - in [DBDesigner 4](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/).

I have 3 tables: `module`, `page`, and `lang`. Each module belongs to a page, and each page has a specific language:

---

[image: DBDesigner 4 schema]

---

Is there a particular reason foreign key `page_lang_tag` is automatically added to the `module` table? The way I see, it should be possible to determine the language of any given module without `module.page_lang_tag`.

I understand that it can be used for more optimized queries, but the full scheme that I'm working on has more complex relationships, and the amount of foreign keys build up *very* quickly.

That is, if I were to add a new table called `widget`, with each of its rows belonging to one module, then the `widget.module_id`, `widget.module_page_id`, and `widget.module_page_lang_tag` all would be automatically created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble started with table `page` whose field `lang_tag` is foreign key (FK) from table `lang` but it is also part of the primary key (PK) of the table. I know this because the PKs are depicted by DBDesigner using a yellow key and FKs have red keys (if they are not red then forgive my memories, I did not use DBDesigner since 2010 and I don't have a copy at hand).

Because of the relationship between `page` and `module`, the PK of table `page` (i.e. both columns `id` and `lang_tag`) migrated as FK in table `module` where, again, they were needlessly added to the table's PK.

I cannot tell if you added `lang_tag` to the PK of table `page` or DBDesigner automatically does this but this is not correct (you don't need it and you don't want it).

Remove `lang_tag` from the PK of `page` and `page_lang_tag` will disappear from table `module`. Also, remove `page_id` from the PK of table `module`.

Comment: It turns out the origin of my issue was that the relationships were all identifying, that's why the foreign keys were part of the primary.